# How do you force the navigation and extension buttons to appear on a pop-up window in Chrome?

Tags: chrome

Sometimes a link on a website causes a new browser window to pop up and sometimes this window doesn't show any navigation buttons, the options menu, or any extension buttons.

For example, this occurs when you "pop-out" a chat window in gmail:

[image: gmail popped-out chat window]

How can I force the navigation and extension buttons to appear?